# How to make particular nodes near coords labels bold in a pgfplots bar chart?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart, nodes-near-coords, histogram

A follow up question to [my previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/372228/how-to-make-particular-xticklabels-bold-in-a-pgfplots-histogram): I am trying to plot a simple bar chart. The data is read and sorted from a csv file. However I couldn't able to change the style of particular labels (nodes near coords) in my plot.

Currently what I am doing:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
ags,uti
Fa,0.7304292882
At,0.7160872752
My,0.7003791749
YX,0.7582041393
Cat,0.7333942111
\textbf{EO15},0.7265476631
\textbf{EC15},0.7587056233
\textbf{DO15},0.7208403111
\textbf{DC15},0.7593885174
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{data.csv}\results
\pgfplotstablesort[sort key={uti}]{\utilsortedresults}{\results}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[]
\centering  
  \begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture} 
  \begin{axis}[
  xbar,
  yticklabels from table={\utilsortedresults}{ags},
  xticklabel style={
        /pgf/number format/fixed,
        /pgf/number format/precision=3
  },
  xmin=0.65,
  width=12cm, 
  height=7cm,
  enlarge y limits=0.1, 
  xticklabel style = {rotate=45,anchor=north east},
  ytick=data, nodes near coords, nodes near coords align={horizontal}, 
  every node near coord/.append style={
        /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,
        /pgf/number format/precision=3
  },
  ] 

  \addplot table[y expr=\coordindex, x={uti}, col sep=comma] \utilsortedresults {};

  \end{axis} 
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Outputs:

[image: Output]

What I am trying to achieve is: making circled labels(as shown below) **bold**:

[image: Expected]

Comment: It would be great if you could make a complete example that doesn't rely on other files we don't have (i.e. your data file).

Comment: I changed the example, it should generate the same plot without relying on other files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If editing the CSV is a possibility here, then I'd add a new column with the value 1 where the ticklabel and `node near coord` should be bold, and 0 elsewhere. You can then use that to decide the formatting of both.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
ags,uti,bold
Fa,0.7304292882,0
At,0.7160872752,0
My,0.7003791749,0
YX,0.7582041393,0
Cat,0.7333942111,0
EO15,0.7265476631,1
EC15,0.7587056233,1
DO15,0.7208403111,1
DC15,0.7593885174,1
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{data.csv}\results
\pgfplotstablesort[sort key={uti}]{\utilsortedresults}{\results}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering  
  \begin{tikzpicture} 
  \begin{axis}[
  xbar,
  ytick=data,
  yticklabel={%
   % \ticknum is the tick number, counting from 0
   % \pgfplotstablegetelem gets a value from the given table,
   % using row number and column name, and saves it to \pgfplotsretval
   \pgfplotstablegetelem{\ticknum}{bold}\of\utilsortedresults
   \ifnum \pgfplotsretval = 1
     \pgfplotstablegetelem{\ticknum}{ags}\of\utilsortedresults
     \textbf{\pgfplotsretval}
    \else
     \pgfplotstablegetelem{\ticknum}{ags}\of\utilsortedresults
     \pgfplotsretval
    \fi},
  xmin=0.65,
  xmax=0.775,
  width=12cm, 
  height=7cm,
  enlarge y limits=0.1, 
  xticklabel style = {
        /pgf/number format/fixed,
        /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill, % assuming you want that
        /pgf/number format/precision=3,
        rotate=45,
        anchor=north east},
  nodes near coords={%
    % same as above, only using \coordindex instead of \ticknum
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{\coordindex}{bold}\of\utilsortedresults
    \ifnum \pgfplotsretval = 1
       {\boldmath\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=3]{\pgfplotspointmeta}}
    \else
            \pgfmathprintnumber[precision=3]{\pgfplotspointmeta}
    \fi
},
  nodes near coords align={horizontal}, 
  every node near coord/.append style={
        /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,
        /pgf/number format/precision=3
  },
  ] 

  \addplot table[y expr=\coordindex, x={uti}, col sep=comma] \utilsortedresults {};

  \end{axis} 
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this with using key names, for instance giving a list ["Fa", "EO15"]? Another thought is: It'd be very helpful if this can be done by directly from the csv file. For example, marking the key with star perhaps.

Comment: @tdgunes You said in your question that you would prefer to do it *without* editing the csv file ... But see edited answer for a suggestion that does involve editing the file.

Comment: Sorry, solution didn't feel elegant enough. From csv file, it seems much more convenient now.